# How to execute an action on a component with a button of an external object?

Tags: java, swing, awt, jbutton

It was hard to word the title for this one, but here's the explanation:

I have a menu bar that I'm adding as an external object from my MenuBar.java that extends JMenuBar to my main program file APP.java that extends JFrame.

MenuBar and a JPanel (which is in my main program file, APP.java) are added to the JFrame.  How do I make buttons from the MenuBar perform actions on the JPanel.

Here's how my JMenuItem objects look like right now in MenuBar.java:

```
    item = new JMenuItem("New);
    item.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_N);
    item.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_N,
            ActionEvent.ALT_MASK));
    item.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            JLabel block = new JLabel();
            block.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(120, 160));

            //***This is where I run into a problem... I want to add this JLabel to my JPanel in
            // the main file, and I also want to revalidate/repaint the JPanel to take show
            // the new JPanels as they're added.....
        }
    });
    file.add(item);
```

I'm not sure if I need to extend my APP to implement ActionListener.... but then I am not sure what to do afterwards.

**EDIT:**

Well, I was able to perform the intended action by making my content panel public and static, thus making it available without instantiating the APP object.  And then I was able to implement this code into my actionPerormed methods in ActionListeners:

```
            APP.content.add(new Thumb());
            APP.content.validate();
```

Thumb() method creates a new JLabel;

Hopefully this won't mess up my stuff later on down the line, being that my content panel is static now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is hard to answer.

I would use `setAction(Action)` (indirectly). One can make an Action as child of AbstractAction, and an Action can hold its text, an icon, mnemonic key and more.

One typical usage is a JTextPane that provides a `Action[] getActios()` and those actions might be added to the menu bar or a JToolBar.

Please look up some code samples.

I leave it at this half of an answer.

An [intro](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html).

Comment: Problem is that all the code I see as sample out there is formed into one file.  I'm trying to separate them to make it easier for myself to work with them, rather than having one huge wall of code.  I tried implementing ActionListener with my JFrame in the main file, and then adding actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) with switch(e.getActionCommand())  case "new": //create a new JLabel add it to content panel... and it didn't work.

Comment: Yes it's hard, a lot of plumbing. I have seen XML to define that menubar, annotations to turn normal functions in event handlers. And so on. In your case it migt be easiest to first go to a MVC (model view controller) separation. And then niceify the code. Maybe the "obsolete" swing application framework is still around.

Comment: Thank you, I'll read up on MVC.  I'm new with Java, so I'm steering away from XAML/XML/JavaFX for now, so that I can learn the basics of the language better.  Writing GUI with XML does seem a lot easier from what I've seen so far (I haven't actually done it).  Looks like people even using styling sheets, which is amazing.

Answer (score 2):

It would depend on what actions you want to perform, but the overall solution is the same. You need to pass a reference of the object of the object you want to work with to the menu class.

If you can, its better to pass a model of interace, limiting your actions to only performing work you really want them to

Comment: Well, I'm trying to add a new JPanel to my content panel.  When I click "New" button from my JMenuBar which was added from MenuBar.java to APP.java, I want the content JPanel to have a new JLabel in it, and then another and another and another, so basically filling it with JLabels.

Comment: The question is about responsibility.  Whose responsible for updating the main window?  To my mind, I tend to provide an interface to these type of actions that says "You can ask me to create something new" (for instance).  This means that the action doesn't care about how that gets done, just that it gets done.  It decouples your code and if you take advantage of the [Action API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html), makes them usable.

Comment: Hmm, what you said there actually makes an awesome point.  I never thought of it like that.  It makes things a lot more clear and easier to design when viewed in that perspective.  Thank you very much.  Over the past month or two that I've had my pleasure of getting your feedback on SO, you've been extremely helpful and knowledgeable.

Comment: I try to be helpful, not sure about knoweldgabel though, I'm sure I have more to learn ;)